# Unity is loading an empty gameobject into list even though the prefab exists UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to do a code where a gameobject is added to a list when the code runs. No errors however the code just adds an empty gameobject even though a specific one has been identified.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class HomeScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> myCollection;
    public int money = 1000;
    [SerializeField] public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI currentMoney;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myCollection.Add(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Assets/Resources/dogPrize.prefab"));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentMoney.text = "Money: $" + money.ToString();
    
    }
    public void buyScreen()
   {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneName:"Buy Screen");
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

[image: Actual Output]

Where the game object is located:

[image: Where the game object is located]

Expected result:

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), the path you pass to `Resources.Load` is relative to the `Resources` directory, and must not contain the extension, so it should be this:

```
    myCollection.Add(Resources.Load<GameObject("dogPrize"));
```